# How much maximum data can we hard commit in Solr?

Tags: solr

I want to know that how much data I can commit in Solr using hard commit. I am not using soft commit.
Below is my configuration

```
<autoCommit>
    <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:1000}</maxTime> 
    <openSearcher>true</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>
```

I removed `<autoSoftCommit>` configuration.
Actually, the issue is, when I am indexing documents, some of the documents are getting deleted from cache.

When I index approx. 25325 documents at a time then document not getting deleted but when I index approx. 70000 documents at a time then few of the documents getting deleted.

**Hardware Configuration :**
RAM - 4GB
JVM Memory - 512 MB

Comment: Are you sure that your uniqueKey-field is actually unique? Later documents with the same key will overwrite earlier documents - this is also true within the same commit.

Comment: Yes. Overwriting is performing. It is true. But why documents are getting deleted.

Comment: Unique key has **string** data type.

Comment: There shouldn't be any deletions, but if you have several documents with the same uniqueKey in the data you're importing, only one of them will be present in the index when you're finished. So if 5% of the 70000 documents has the same uniqueKey, you'll only have 66500 documents in the index when you're finished.

Comment: Thanks.. Got your point.

Comment: @ MatsLindh: you are telling that take only unique keys in the data. Now I have only unique keys in the data. At first time indexing. I am indexing 100000 documents with unique keys only.They are indexing well without any deletions. But when I am indexing next 100000 documents may contains same uniqueKey data which were inside previous 100000 documents. So, now there are deleting. How to fix it? I only want to do AtomicUpdate on the indexing data without losing them, if there are already present in indexed data.

Comment: If you really have duplicate keys - you're not losing them, you're just overwriting them with a new document (which is a delete + insert). Have you actually confirmed that a document with a given uniqueKey is not in the index afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, documents are available in data. **delete + insert** is happening and AtomicUpdates is also working. Thanks a Lot. `@MatsLindh`